# jQueryUI - Accordion Scrolling to header freezes when same section opened twice in a row

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the following to control my accordion:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    autoHeight: false, collapsible: true, active: false
  });

  $('#accordion').bind('accordionchange', function (event, ui) {
    $(window).scrollTop(ui.newHeader.offset().top);
  });
});
```

It works well unless I open the same section twice. Then, the accordion freezes and I get the following error:

ui.newHeader.offset() is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `accordionchange` event appears to be the jQuery event that corresponds to the accordion's `activate` event; yes, this is a bit confusing but that's what the [source tells me](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1-9-stable/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js#L663):

```
// change events
(function( $, prototype ) {
    //...
        } else if ( type === "activate" ) {
            ret = _trigger.call( this, "change", event, {
```

The [`activate` documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) has this to say:

> **activate( event, ui )**
>
> Triggered after a panel has been activated (after animation completes). [...] If the accordion is collapsing, `ui.newHeader` and `ui.newPanel` will be empty jQuery objects.

So your `ui.newHeader` is an empty jQuery object and empty jQuery objects don't have `offset()`s. A quick length check on `ui.newHeader` will probably sort you out:

```
$('#accordion').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
    if(ui.newHeader.length)
        $(window).scrollTop(ui.newHeader.offset().top);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/e3gUW/